# How to map dynamic fields from MongoDB to model Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-mongodb

I try to map dynamic fields of a document in mongodb collection to a model in spring boot project,
well this is the document from mongodb

**Example of MongoDB Document**

```
{
  "_id":"5f78e5599fe104f27eb61333",
  "conducteur":{
    "cin":"F21458",
    "nomComplet":"Ahmed Ayoub",
    "idConducteur":"4"
  },
  "vehicule":{
     "matricule":"4585|45| a",
     "engin":"Benne", 
     "idVehicule":"1"
  },
  "date":"21-11-2019 22:07:44",
  "site":"Paris",
  "rating":37.04,
  "etat":true,
  "imageUrl":null,
  "motif":"nothing",
  "controlleur":{"cin":"F44585","nomComplet":"Test","idController":"2"},
  "checklistConducteur":[false,true,false,true,true],
  "checklistEquipement":[false,false,false,true,true],
  "checklistEngin":[false,true,true,false,true,false,true],
  "checklistAttelage":[true,true,true,false,true]
}
```

Then I create the model with the standards or fixed fields and one field to handle dynamic properties, the model seems like

```
@Document(collection = "checkList")
public class CheckList {

    private String id;
    private Map<String, String> conducteur;
    private Map<String, String> vehicule;
    private Date date;
    private String site;
    private double rating;
    private boolean etat;
    private String imageUrl;
    private String motif;
    private Map<String, String> controlleur;
    private Map<String, Boolean[]> catchAll = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Boolean[]> getCatchAll() {
        return catchAll;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setCatchAll(Map<String, Boolean[]> catchAll) {
        this.catchAll = catchAll;
    }
}
```

So what i want is to combine or map **checklistConducteur**, **checklistEquipement**, **checklistEngin** and **checklistAttelage** from mongodb document to the field **catchAll**, or to get nested inside it.

I tried to use the annotations like @JsonAnyGetter, @JsonAnySetter, or to create a class CatchAll have these properties, but give me the same result:

**API Response:**

```
{
   "id": "5f78e5599fe104f27eb61333",
   "conducteur": {
       "cin": "F21458",
       "nomComplet": "Ahmed Ayoub",
       "idConducteur": "4"
   },
   "vehicule": {
        "matricule": "4585|45| a",
        "engin": "Benne",
        "idVehicule": "1"
   },
   "date": "21-11-2019 22:07:44",
   "site": "Paris",
   "rating": 37.04,
   "etat": true,
   "imageUrl": null,
   "motif": "nothing",
   "controlleur": {
      "cin": "F44585",
      "nomComplet": "Test",
      "idController": "2"
   },
   "catchAll": {}
}
```

**what i want as result from API:**

```
"catchAll": {
   "checklistConducteur":[false,true,false,true,true],
   "checklistEquipement":[false,false,false,true,true],
   "checklistEngin":[false,true,true,false,true,false,true],
   "checklistAttelage":[true,true,true,false,true]
}
```

If anyone has a solution or suggestion please help me, I will be thankful.

Comment: Are trying to get the mapped catchAll in your API response or when mapping the data from mongodb to Java objects?

Comment: Why you don't do one-to-one binding and you postpone combining/merging/processing to other service layer ? (I'm not a fan having 'gaps' between DB schema and model)

Comment: @Ismail Mapping the data from mongodb to java objects,

Comment: @M.Mas. can u clarify your point please, because i am a new developer in java environment, i used to develope with .Net technologies.

Comment: @Miidow, my point is agnostic from technology. In fact, why you are trying to read those arrays in catchAll field? Why you dont't retrieve directly arrays in other arrays  (on you model)

Comment: @M.Mas.Because those arrays are dynamic fields, i can have another one with different key, and value, so that's i want to all dyanmic fields in catchAll.